# Tools for developing native Linux / MacOSX applications in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, linux, macos, cordova

Please advise on tools that can be used to develop native applications in Javascript. By native application I mean an application that user can start from a command line. I am not talking here about WEB applications that user runs entering URL in the browser.
Apache Cordova is a similar tool for developing native apps in Javascript for mobile platforms (Android, iOS, etc.) yet I could not find info on how to use Cordova to develop apps targeted to Linux / Mac OSX platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit
It allows you to create a "deskop" applications.

Comment: Your question and comment is both confusing and contradicting. Why you want to use cordova to target desktop apps? And then complain for no support for mobile platforms if you want to target desktop apps...